# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Where are the proxy settings for push notification?

Tags: android, proxy, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

In IBM Worklight 6.0 Information Center, I can [find the GCM proxy settings for push notification](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/r_push_notification_settings.html?resultof=%22proxy.push%22%20). But there is no instruction about where to set it up.

Comment: Is this question resolved?

Answer (score 0):

In your Eclipse installation, navigate to `yourProject\server\conf\worklight.properties` and search for `Push GCM proxy settings`. You will find the following commented out section: 
[image]

Input your values based on what you've read in the Information Center and your network setting. Consult with your IT department.